# Can we hide apps installed on our phone using MDM?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, mdm

I have a requirement where i have to  hide some specific apps on the phone once the app which i am developing is installed on the phone.I will be using MDM , i want to know is it possible to hide other apps using MDM.

Comment: Upto iOS7 you can hide apps using SBAppTags key in app-info.plist. from iOS8 onwards the key is obsolete you can't hide the apps. As per apples guideline, the apps should not be hidden from the home screen.  as per this MDM provides https://appblade.com/features it is possible to hide the app from the device.

Comment: Are you referring to base iOS apps? If so which ones?

Comment: You can blacklist the apps using MDM. I am not sure what you mean by hide an app?

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do that with the **Restriction** feature of the Apple MDM

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/restrictions

You can blicklist the iOS apps from the home launcher and apps will be hidden for that device, The only condition is you can only use this feature in supervised iOS devices.

[image]

You can make your iphone supervised with 2 methods:

1. Apple Business Manager or DEP (Over the air or automated enrollment)
2. Manual or self enrollment using apple configurator 2